# Chinese character gash when using SQLAPI++

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005, sqlapi++

I use SQLAPI++ to insert data into SQL Server 2005. When there are many Chinese characters, it will be garbled in database.

IDE : MS 2005

IDE Character Set : Multi-Byte

SQLAPI Lib : sqlapi.lib(dynamic release import library for MSVC++)

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a way to store the Chinese Characters in SQL Server database, Then you should Try storing the same into an NVARCHAR field. also, prefix the Caracter N (Case sensitive) before the string. Like this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    StrChar VARCHAR(50),
    StrChar2 VARCHAR(50),
    StrNVar NVARCHAR(100),
    StrNVar2 NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('诶',N'诶','诶',N'诶')

SELECT
    *
    FROM @T
```

I got the result like this

[image]

Comment: When I add N, I got `²àÎ§`. When I don't use it, I got `2à?§`.

Comment: Might be an issue with the IDE that you are using, Try with the SSMS